# Auth-Attempt Laravel 5.8 Just Refreshes to Login Again

Tags: php, laravel

The `Auth::attempt()` function returns true but it redirects to login again:

```
public function getData(Request $request) {

    if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->input('username'), 'password' => $request->input('password')])) {

        
        if (Auth()->user()->role == "admin") {

            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }
        else if (Auth()->user()->role == 'farmer') {

            return redirect('/farmer/dashboard');
        }
        else if (Auth()->user()->role == 'invest') {
            return redirect('/invest/dashboard');
        }
    }
    return redirect('/login')->with('error', 'username or password false');
}
```

And it's my route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
  Route::get('/dashboard', 'c_admin@index');
});
```

If I place outside route group it redirects to dashboard.

Comment: what are you getting inside `Auth()->user()->role`